# How to update the marker's position by fetching the latitude and longitude from the database by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to fetch the latest latitude and longitude from the database table every time I click the Button. I want this to happen by changing the markers position on maps but without refreshing the whole page. 
I am using php, and javascript

````
<?php
    include 'db_connect.php';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM soldier ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count == 1)
    {
        $lat_d = $row['latitude'];
        $long_d = $row['longitude'];
        $pulse = $row['pulse'];
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "failure";
    }
?>`


<div class="container">
    <center class = "container">
    <center><h1>Geo-Location</h1></center>
<div id="map"></div>

<div class="two-mid-button d-flex justify-content-center mt-lg-5 mt-md-4 mt-sm-4 mt-3">
    <div class="view-buttn">
        <button value="Refresh Page" class="button"        onClick="window.location.reload()">Refresh
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var map;
    function initMap()
    {
        var myLatLng = {lat: <?php echo $lat_d; ?>, lng: <?php echo $long_d; ?>};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        {
            center: myLatLng,
            zoom: 10
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
        });
    }
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBk3R_ceCa_Qz9_7-6rLVxACwyw27HP7XU&callback=initMap"
async defer></script> ```
````